# How to compare performances of AVRO and parquet file formats in streamsets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, avro, parquet, streamsets

Both avro and parquet files were successfully stored in GCS. Is there any way to compare their performances in streamsets

Comment: Could you described your process and elaborate more on what you want to compare?

Answer (score 0):

Avro is a row based data format and Parquet is a row columnar data format so it really depends on your use case. Check out this [great article on things to consider](https://towardsdatascience.com/demystify-hadoop-data-formats-avro-orc-and-parquet-e428709cf3bb) when deciding which one to use.

Cheers,
Dash